# Can not remove VirtualBox Guest Additions with "apt-get remove" command

Tags: apt, package-management, removing

I have tried to remove package with "remove" command, but there was not any request to delete it, even though something was found. I'm newbie, so maybe I made something wrong?

```
vic@vic-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-guest*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-guest-utils' for glob 'virtualbox-guest*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-guest-modules' for glob 'virtualbox-guest*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-guest-additions-iso' for glob 'virtualbox-guest*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-guest-dkms' for glob 'virtualbox-guest*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-guest-dkms-hwe' for glob 'virtualbox-guest*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-guest-modules-hwe' for glob 'virtualbox-guest*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-guest-x11-hwe' for glob 'virtualbox-guest*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-guest-source' for glob 'virtualbox-guest*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-guest-source-hwe' for glob 'virtualbox-guest*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-guest-utils-hwe' for glob 'virtualbox-guest*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-guest-x11' for glob 'virtualbox-guest*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-guest-additions' for glob 'virtualbox-guest*'
Package 'virtualbox-guest-additions' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-guest-modules-hwe' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-guest-additions-iso' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-guest-dkms-hwe' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-guest-source-hwe' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-guest-utils-hwe' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-guest-x11-hwe' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-guest-dkms' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-guest-source' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-guest-utils' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'virtualbox-guest-x11' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 381 not upgraded.
```

#

```
vic@vic-VirtualBox:~$ ls opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-*
ls: cannot access 'opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-*': No such file or directory
vic@vic-VirtualBox:~$ dpkg -l | grep -i virtualbox
vic@vic-VirtualBox:~$ sudo vbox-uninstall-guest-additions
[sudo] password for vic: 
Removing installed version 5.2.18 of VirtualBox Guest Additions...
vic@vic-VirtualBox:~$ ^C
vic@vic-VirtualBox:~$
```

Comment: Please add output of the `dpkg -l | grep -i virtualbox` and `ls /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-*` to the question.

Comment: So you can accept my answer below :) For the future remember that first `/` is necessary to access root of the file-system (so correct path is `/opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-*` and not `opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-*`).

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you have installed VirtualBox Guest Additions from ISO-file. In such case they were installed to the system without help of APT (so `apt-get` and `dpkg` will not know about them).

You should run the following command to remove VirtualBox Guest Additions from guest system:

```
sudo vbox-uninstall-guest-additions
```

After removal you will not have guest additions folder `/opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-*`.